# Meaning of projection onto one factor in $0\to A^{r-1}\to A^r\to A\to 0$

Tags: solution-verification, notation, modules, exact-sequence, epimorphisms

The following is taken from: $\textit{Partial Differential Control Theory Vol 1: Mathematical tools}$ by J F. Pommaret

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{Definition 1.50.}$  $M$ is call a $\textit{free module}$ if it has a $\textit{basis},$ that is a system of generators linearly independent over $A.$  When $M$ is free, the number of generators in a basis is called the $\textit{rank}$ of $M$ and does not depend on the basis if it is finite.  Indeed, if $\{x_i\}$ and $\{y_j\}$ are two bases and $y_j=\sum {a^i}_jx_i,$ then $\text{det}({a^i}_j)$ must be invertible in $A.$ If $M$ is free of rank $n,$ then $M\cong A^n.$

$\textbf{Lemma 1.54.}$  In a short exact sequence of modules:

$$0\to M'\xrightarrow{f}M\xrightarrow{g}M''\to 0$$

the module $M$ is noetherian if and only if the momdules $M'$ and $M''$ are noetherian.

$\textbf{Proposition 1.55.}$  If $A$ is a noetherian ring and $M$ is a finitely generated $A-$module, then $M$ is a noetherian module.

> $\textit{Proof.}$  Applying the preceding lemma (Lemma 1.54) to the short exact sequence $0\to A^{r-1}\to A^r\to A\to 0$ where the right epimorphism is the projection onto one factor, we deduce by induction that $A''$ is a noetherian module.  Now, if $M$ is generated by $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ then there is an epimorphism $A^n\to M:(1,0,\ldots,0)\to x_1,\ldots,(0,\ldots,0,1)\to x_n.$ According to the preceding lemma, $M$ is a noetherian module too.

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

In the beginning of the above proof, I am not clear on which right morphism the author is referring to in the sentence:  "Applying the preceding lemma (Lemma 1.54) to the short exact sequence $0\to A^{r-1}\to A^r\to A\to 0$ where the right epimorphism is the projection onto one factor..." What does the author mean by projection onto one factor?   My understanding is that if we have a map, we can project one of the element of the domain onto the function's range.  So say $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}, (x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto x_i.$  In the case of $A^{r-1}\to A^r,$ are Could the author meant, given cannoical basis elements $(e_1,e_2,\ldots e_{r-1})$ in $A^{r-1},$ I pick an $e_i$ to project onto $A^r$ so $A^{r-1}\to A^r$ is the map $(e_1,e_2,\ldots e_{r-1})\mapsto (0_1,...0_{i-1},e_i,0_i,...0_{r-1},0_r)$?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example when $r = 3$, the first map $A^2\to A^3$ could be
\begin{align*}
(1,0)&\mapsto (1,0,0)\\
(0,1)&\mapsto (0,0,1),
\end{align*}
and then the second map $A^3\to A$ would be (it has to be this for the overall sequence to be exact)
\begin{align*}
(1,0,0)&\mapsto 0,\\
 (0,1,0)&\mapsto 1,\\
 (0,0,1) &\mapsto 0.
\end{align*}
This second map is an example of "projection onto the second factor."
You can check that this gives a short exact sequence $0\to A^2\to A^3\to A \to 0$.

Generally, the author means that we include $A^{r-1}$ into $A^r$ by leaving one coordinate $0$ in $A^r$, and then we project $A^r$ onto the factor of $A$ that we left as $0$ in the inclusion $A^{r-1}\hookrightarrow A^r$.

Comment: the right epimorphism the author is talking about, he is talking about one of the two projection map, or is he only referring to $A^r\to A$ or $A\to 0$?

Comment: @Seth, he means the map $A^r\to A$

Comment: so the factor here is referring to going from $A^r$ to $A$ where $r=1$ and he is talking about the size of the basis of vector space in the domain is being projected into another vector space having of smaller size and hence less basis element, in this case $r=1.$  The author's phrasing is confusing, since I am not sure which interpretation I am to understand.

Comment: @Seth, $A^r = A\times\dots\times A$ (with $r$ total factors). When the author says "the right epimorphism is the projection onto one factor," he means that we choose one of the coordinate projections $\pi_1,\dots,\pi_r$, each of which is separately defined by $\pi_i(x_1,\dots,x_r) = x_i$ to be the map $A^r\to A$. Which one do we choose? It depends on which inclusion $A^{r-1}\to A^r$ we chose. There are $r$ natural inclusions $\iota_1,\dots,\iota_r:A^{r-1}\to A^r$, each of which is separately defined by choosing one of the factors of $A^r$ and leaving it as $0$; we choose $\pi_i$ accordingly

Comment: ah kk.  i think that makes sense to me  now. THank you.